# Finding focal length from image size and FOV

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision

I have bumped into the following statement in an [Engineering journal](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/49159361/vision-based-acc-with-a-single-camera-bounds-on-mobileye/3). The statement is mentioned on right side example.

> A 640x480 image with a horizontal FOV of 47 degrees gives focal length
>   f = 740 pixels.

Please let me know the calculations behind this as I am very new to Computer vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU `740` is not the exact answer for such data but close enough. According to my understanding

```
f = (width/2) * ctg(HFOV/2)
```

which give me `f = 735.95`. And to reverse for `f = 740` the `HFOV` should be `46.77°`.

The math behind is following: assume that on their Figure 2 `Y1` is actually the top point on the sensor (I'll use vertical field of view here instead of horizontal because it allows me to use that image). Now consider the triangle `O-P-Y1`. In that triangle `∠P` is half of the `FOV`. On the other hand `ctg(∠P)` = `ctg(FOV/2)` is `OP/OY1` which is `f/(height/2)`.

Comment: That solved my question. Thanks a lot..